# Position change. How to start a talk with boss if I'm confused with his arrangment?

Tags: communication

I graduated from uni last September. I've got a job as a administrative secretary in finance department. The company is foreign invested and the job is well-paid. Even though being an administrative staff is quite tired I’ve got used to it quite quick. Honestly, I’ve started loving my job, I love giving support to the accountants in my department, I try my best to take good care of them since accountant is a crazy job that often drives people crazy when it comes to closing.

After 6 months working as an administrative secretary, my boss asks me to change my position from a secretary to assistant and asked me to prepare for huge load of work. I was pretty excited at that time. New tasks mean new experience, moreover, I’ve already been able to handle my current work quite well and feel like it will turn boring soon.

I’ve got my work handed over as arranged. Then I started merely sitting in the office every day. My boss didn’t give me any assignment. It has been 3 weeks since the day I finished handing over my job to the new secretary. I’ve started feeling unsecured. The other assistant seems overloaded since he has to work overtime a lot. His major is accounting, hence, I can’t suggest to help him in anything. I don’t want to do it anyway, because we’re not close and I’m not assigned. In this Asian company, it’s really important to not stick your nose to others’ things.

I’m so disappointed. My colleagues ask me to talk to the boss and ask him to give me assignment. I don’t feel like so. I’m the one who is asked to change the position and now I have to ask him to give me assignment? I wonder if he’s trying to imply that I should leave instead of firing me directly!? 
(***in my country, the labor law doesn't allow employee to fire employer unless he/she commit a crime in the course of working. I know it may sound weird but it's true. Moreover, asian always tends to implying instead of making direct talk. That's why I think he's implying I should quit)

I know I can just find another job. But I’m not satisfied with this ending.

Additionally, he had complained about my attitude when I went to him and said that I would quit after the probation had finished (at that time I didn't like my job and found it nonsense). He think I should have try to make a negotiation/discussion with him instead of being so hostile, coming to him and declared that I would quit.

My boss is a foreigner. We have some significant difference in mindset not only because of culture but also because of generation gap (25+ years older). That's why I've found it hard to make expressive communication with him.

Should I try talking to him directly? If so, how to start the conservation when I cannot start it directly? Or I'd better ask my colleague to help me make it clear?

**personal question: do you think I overthink? Should I enjoy my leisure while still being paid? (guilty me)

Comment: "I don’t feel like so. I’m the one who is asked to change to job and now I have to ask him to give me assignment?" What is this??? Listen to your colleagues. Your boss is probably busy. He doesn't have the time to monitor you and hold you by the hand. Ask him. There is no other way around that. If you're too introverted or shy to be able to ask for work, then they may just let you go.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, That has absolutely nothing to do with this question, and is rather rude. What does it matter if OP has loans? What does it matter what OP chooses to do with his/her degree? What OP chooses to do with his/her degree falls under the "What should I do category?" and users who ask such questions would be reprimanded, so it makes no sense to ask a question which forces the user to answer such a thing. The loans part MIGHT be applicable if this were in Money/Personal Finance SE. This question itself probably falls under "What should I do?", so just VTC and move on.

Comment: "  I've got a job as a secretary in finance cum accounting department. " what?

Comment: @Jon She's THAT secretary from all the jokes ...

Comment: @Jon: sorry for making you confused, they combined accounting depart with finance depart and here come the name. It's so odd but we tend to use it (for fun) lol

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: thank you for your words dear. May be u r right, I'm shy. It's not that easy to talk to the boss, specially when he's more than 2 decades older than me and also 30+cm taller. The thing I'm afraid most is that Taiwanese always play drama and politics. I'm not sure about talking directly. People here are old, i'm the youngest among them and the gap is big. Most of the time, they treat me like a little girl. Those malice look at me like I'm a kid. It hurts my confidence when it comes to argument or convincement.

Answer (score 8):

If your boss is the one who assigns work to you then you need to speak to the boss about getting work.  That isn't crazy, it's what you are supposed to do.

Comment: I also follow your reasoning. Also it shows a willingness to contribute. Don't however storm into your boss his office and demand work. Just clearly indicate you completed the handover, and are waiting for your next assignment. I don't know whether it's appropriate in Asian company culture to do so, but it seems like the best solution if you want to have some extra workload. Also, if you still are without much to do, start doing some research, try to learn something new, etc...

Comment: @smikkels: I do, learning and researching everyday. Sometimes it's kinna boring though. You've got it. It's Asian company and here is Asia. We don't talk, we imply. I think the fact that I'm fresh bring out everything. I'll try to get some freelance jtranslation to kill the time and make me feel a bit useful :(